# calling a modular window component through another file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api

Guys please tell me how I can implement the modal window approach. 
Let's say I have in the main component: `<button @click="Modal">open</button>.`
I want it to open and close. i.e. all the logic like: close on esc, click outside the modal, click on the cross. Was inside the modal window, so that I would not drag all the refs behind me.
This is not convenient. I only want to click to pull the entire component and that it would open and close inside the modal window component. I tried to make a big props up to what, I will transfer the button itself to the modal window, but I do not like this approach, as I can do in the modal window, opening closing, not to write refs in other files. 
See how I'm trying to get an approximate result: [play.vuejs.org](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)
But I don't like this approach because I have to shove styles into props and so on.

I'm trying to achieve this result:

```
<script setup>
import Modal from './Modal';
</sctipt>  
<template>
<button @click="Modal">Open Modal</button>
<Modal v-if="Modal">data...</Modal>
</template>
```

Is it possible to achieve the desired result? Can you tell me which way to dig?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To achieve the desired result of having a modal window open and close within the modal window component itself without passing props or using refs directly in the parent component, you can utilize Vue's reactivity system along with event handling.

Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
<template>
  <button @click="openModal">Open Modal</button>
  <Modal :show="modalVisible" @close="closeModal">Modal content...</Modal>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Modal from './Modal';

const modalVisible = ref(false);

const openModal = () => {
  modalVisible.value = true;
};

const closeModal = () => {
  modalVisible.value = false;
};
</script>
```

And your Modal component would look something like this:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="show" class="modal-overlay" @click="closeModalOutside">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <button class="close-button" @click="closeModal">X</button>
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, watch, getCurrentInstance, defineProps } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
  show: Boolean
});

const instance = getCurrentInstance();
const show = ref(false);

const closeModalOutside = (event) => {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('modal-overlay')) {
    closeModal();
  }
};

const closeModal = () => {
  show.value = false;
  instance.emit('close');
};

watch(() => props.show, (newValue) => {
  show.value = newValue;
});
</script>

<style scoped>
.modal-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.close-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

This approach keeps the modal logic encapsulated within the Modal component and avoids the need to pass props or use refs directly in the parent component.

Comment: Wow. That's about what I need. But for some reason the modal window opens only once and does not open again, why?
Would you take a look at this, please? The link is the same play.vuejs.org. (which is in the question).

Comment: You are right, the problem was with emit in the close function, I edited my post and fixed it.

Comment: Thank you. That's pretty much what I was trying to accomplish.❤️